# how to assign DB Values to HTML textbox in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I am trying to get the database values saved from form into Textbox in same form. The values are loaded whenever the form is loaded. I have written a  example code what I am doing below. I have 5 rows of textboxes. I have written the below code that get the values from database. But my knowledge is limited about getting those five rows of values to the five rows of textboxes either using JSP or JAVAScript. Tried searching online but didn't fine related answer. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<body>
<% 
String processVal = "SELECT  * FROM  NETWORK_ACCESS WHERE PRD_ID=?";
 PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(processVal);
 pst.setString(1, ProcID);
 ResultSet rsProcess=pst.executeQuery();

 while(rsProcess.next())
    {

SIP=rs.getString(2);
DIP=rs.getString(3);
SP=rs.getString(4);
SD=rs.getString(5);
ED=rs.getString(6); 
    }
 %>


<table>
<tr>    
  <th>Sl.No</th>
  <th>SIP</th>
  <th>DIP</th>
  <th>SP</th>
  <th>Start Date</th>
  <th>END Date</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="align:center"> 1 </td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="id" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name1" id="id1" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name2" id="id2" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name3" id="id3" size="15"> <img src="../Image/cal.gif" id="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('name3','MMddyyyy','dropdown',false,'12')" /></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name4" id="id4" size="15"><img src="../Image/cal.gif" id="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('name4','MMddyyyy','dropdown',false,'12')" /> </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td style="align:center"> <label> 2 </label> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name" id="id5" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name1" id="id6" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name2" id="id7" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name3" id="id8" size="15"> <img src="../Image/cal.gif" id="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('name3','MMddyyyy','dropdown',false,'12')" /></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name4" id="id9" size="15"><img src="../Image/cal.gif" id="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('name4','MMddyyyy','dropdown',false,'12')" /> </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td> <label> 3 </label> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name" id="id10" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name1" id="id11" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name2" id="id12" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name3" id="id13" size="15"> <img src="../Image/cal.gif" id="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('name3','MMddyyyy','dropdown',false,'12')" /></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name4" id="id14" size="15"><img src="../Image/cal.gif" id="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('name4','MMddyyyy','dropdown',false,'12')" /> </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td> <label>4 </label> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name" id="id15" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name1" id="id15" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name2" id="id16" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name3" id="id17" size="15"> <img src="../Image/cal.gif" id="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('name3','MMddyyyy','dropdown',false,'12')" /></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name4" id="id18" size="15"><img src="../Image/cal.gif" id="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('name4','MMddyyyy','dropdown',false,'12')" /> </td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
   <td> <label>5 </label> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name" id="id19" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name1" id="id20" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name2" id="id21" size="20"> </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name3" id="id22" size="15"> <img src="../Image/cal.gif" id="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('name3','MMddyyyy','dropdown',false,'12')" /></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name4" id="id23" size="15"><img src="../Image/cal.gif" id="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('name4','MMddyyyy','dropdown',false,'12')" /> </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign classes to  tags. Later, you should do like these with jQuery :

```
var abc = $("thclass1").text();
$("input[name=input1]).val(abc);
var abcd = $("thclass2").text();
$("input[name=input2).val(abcd);
...
```

you should make these each inputs and th tags.

Comment: where should I add classes to tags? are you referring to Input tags. I still didn't understand how to get each row values as it saved.

Answer (score 0):

```
//write table header code here
i = 0;
while(rsProcess.next())
{
   SIP=rs.getString(2);
   DIP=rs.getString(3);
   SP=rs.getString(4);
   SD=rs.getString(5);
   ED=rs.getString(6); 
   i++;
%>
//write code for each row of db
   <tr>
    <td style="align:center"> <c:out value=${i}> </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="id" size="20" value="<c:out value=${SIP}>">
    ..........
   </tr>
<%
}
%>
```

Comment: Akshay, doesn't this display all the values in one row one by one(by this it will only display last row fetched from DB) and not in five different rows?

Comment: I tried the above and it didn't work. It creates a new textbox and assign the value. But not to the existing ones.